# Are B'nei Noach prohibited from learning Torah? Why/why not?

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws, noahidism

I am compelled to ask this because from personal observation, more and more Noahides are studying the Torah WITH the supervision of some Orthodox and non-Orthodox rabbis, although it is also the case that there are those who learn on their own (with the aid of Rashi and other commentaries.) Yet, I thought gentiles are NOT allowed to learn Torah. Is the prohibition only in effect if a gentile is learning on their own?

Comment: The gemara says it doesnt apply to 7 mitzvos and reishonim have a bunch of other cases it doesnt apply to. But im sure theres already a similar question to this somewhere on this website.

Answer (score 1):

In the Talmud, Rabbi Meir said that a Gentile who studies the Torah is like a High Priest, because the Torah says: "וּשְׁמַרְתֶּ֤ם אֶת־חֻקֹּתַי֙ וְאֶת־מִשְׁפָּטַ֔י אֲשֶׁ֨ר יַעֲשֶׂ֥ה אֹתָ֛ם הָאָדָ֖ם וָחַ֣י בָּהֶ֑ם --
Keep my statutes and my judgments, for the man who obeys them will live by them."  [Lev. 18:5]. He adds: It does not say “Priest, Levite, or Israelite”, but *adam* -- “man”.  So we learn that even a Gentile who studies the Torah is like a High Priest!   But another rabbi countered that Gentiles should study only the parts of the Torah that pertain to their own seven Noahide laws, and not the rest. [Sanhedrin 59a, Bava Kamma 38a]  The latter became the rule.

Comment: No, the Rambam said that Judaism is a package deal:  No picking some parts of it and rejecting the rest: "The principle is that one may not make innovations in religion or create new commandments. [Gentiles] may become true converts by accepting all the commandments or they must observe their own (seven Noahide) laws only, and not add or detract from them." [Mishneh Torah, Kings and Wars 10:9]

Comment: chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/… “ 10 We should not prevent a Noachide who desires to perform one of the Torah's mitzvot in order to receive reward from doing so, provided he performs it as required. If he brings an animal to be sacrificed as a burnt offering, we should receive it.”

Comment: There's at least one exception. Rabbi Nachman said, Not only do you have need for me, but the gentiles need me as well. Accordingly you'd have learn about him from his books or his followers.