# Are non-Jews allowed to study the laws that pertain to them?

Tags: torah-study, noachide-laws

Non-Jews are prohibited from Torah study. However, I would be inclined to think that they are allowed, if not encouraged, to study the 7 Commandments for the Descendants of Noach. Is this true? If yes, is there a difference between in-depth and just surface-level study? And, would they be rewarded for such study in the World to Come?

Comment: I would think they're obligated.

Comment: Baba kama 38a a non jew that studies his laws is as great as a kohen gadol

Comment: This is a duplicate that has been answered multiple times. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138964/7303

Comment: Funny, I wasn't able to find these in the search, thanks!

Comment: The search feature is not very good. Try Google.